# How do I give a pointer to a new instantiation of an object?

Tags: javascript

See the following piece of simplified code:

```
myVar= 1;
myFunc = function() {
    return { val : myVar };
};
myInstantiation = new myFunc();
console.log(myInstantiation ); //{val:1}
console.log(myVar); //1
myVar=2;
console.log(myInstantiation );//{val:1}
console.log(myVar); //2
```

is there any way I can declare the `myInstantiation`, or the `myFunc` so as to still do the same thing ( eg instantiate the object ) but in such a way that will allow me to change the `myVar` and have that change reflect inside the `myInstantiation` ?

Eg I want the output to be

```
console.log(myInstantiation );//{val:2}
console.log(myVar); //2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, no (well, you can with ECMAScript5). The expression

```
return { val: myVar };
```

...takes the *value* of `myVar` and assigns it to the `val` property of a new object. There is no enduring connection between that `val` property's value and the value of the `myVar`.

The straightforward way to do what you want is to make `val` a function rather than a property:

```
myVar = 1;
myFunc = function() {
    return {
        val: function() {
            return myVar;
        }
    };
};
myInstantiation = new myFunc();
myVar = 2;
alert(myInstantiation.val()); // alerts "2"
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/aqaqej)

If it *has* to be a property, it's possible with ECMAScript5: You can define a function that gets called when someone accesses an object property, using the new [`Object.defineProperty`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3.6) function:

```
myVar = 1;
myFunc = function() {
    var rv = {};
    Object.defineProperty(rv, "val", {
        get: function() {
            return myVar;
        },
        set: function(newVal) {
            myVar = newVal;
        }
    });
    return rv;
};
myInstantiation = new myFunc();
myVar = 2;
alert(myInstantiation.val); // alerts "2"
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ahozax/2) - run in Chrome, a recent version of Firefox, or a recent Safari (but not Opera or any version, so far, of IE).

It's still a function call, with the overhead that implies, but the code using `myInstantiation` sees it as a property access. (Which is handy, but in some ways misleading.)

`Object.defineProperty` only works with JavaScript engines that support the new ECMAScript5 features, so notably not IE. There's no *standard* way of doing what you're doing without an explicit function call otherwise (Mozilla had done their own thing prior to the standard, but that's now deprecated and only worked in a couple of browsers).

---

There are some issues with your code that I should I should point out:

1. You're not declaring your variables, and so you're falling prey to the [Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).
2. Your `myFunc` is defined as:

   ```
   myFunc = function() {
       return { val: myVar };
   };
   ```

   ...but then you're calling it with `new`:

   ```
   myInstantiation = new myFunc();
   ```

   Since your function returns an object, `new` serves no purpose there, you can just do

   ```
   myInstantiation = myFunc();
   ```

   This is because of the way `new` works: It creates an object, initializes that object with a prototype from `myFunc.prototype`, and then calls `myFunc` with `this` set to the new object. If `myFunc` doesn't return anything or returns a primitive type (or `null`), the result of the `new` expression is the new object that `new` created. But if `myFunc` returns an object (as yours does), the new object created by `new` is thrown away and your object is used instead. So `new` with a function like yours is irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript, certain types are passed by value, while others are passed by reference. In particular, integers and other basic types are passed by value, so you can't directly retrieve a pointer to them.

However, if you used an `Integer` constructor (I can't remember of JavaScript has a standard one), which wraps the primitive integer, you could pass around a pointer to the `Integer` object instead. This would allow updating the value via pointer.

It's been a while since I worked with JavaScript, so I'm not sure if this next idea is feasible. When you instantiate a new function, that function closes over the variables that are currently in scope. This means that you should be able to do something like this:

```
myInstantiation = new myFunc(new function(newValue) { myVar = newValue } );
```

which you could then used from within `myFunc`. (the syntax might be a little off, but the idea should work I think. Like I said, I don't really do JavaScript anymore).

### EDIT

So, yeah, the last part is pointless as far as your question goes - I got the situation backwards. However, you could use the dual function instead:

```
myInstantiation = new myFunc(new function() { return myVar } );
```

By calling the given function instead of directly using `myVar`, the changed should be visible from within `myFunc`. And if you'd like easy two-way communication, you can use both the function from before and this new one to get/set `myVar` from within `myFunc`.